# Leaflet Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I use the framework codeigniter3 
bootrsap 5 called in header.php 
Leaflet map cdn (in view) 
leaflet.fullscreen cdn (in view) 
jquery cdn (in view)

1st step in mode fullscreen off (worked fine)

```
<script>
 $("#map").css('z-index', 0);
 $(".sidebar").css('position', 'absolute')
 $(".sidebar").css('z-index', 1);
 $(".sidebar").draggable();
 $(".card-header-sidebar").css('cursor', 'grab');
</script>
```

when i change fullscreen ok ( my problem )

i want to keep the sidebar visible

[Full screen off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0kxp.png)
[full screen on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJl7z.png)

Comment: try to inspect the #map after you use fullscreen and see if the Z-index is still 0, also chek if the .sidebar still there and what is its css properties after fullscreen, maybe fullscreen is changing some properties on #map

Comment: console.log($('#map').css('z-index'));
Return :  0

Answer (score 0):

There are no solution for fullscreen leaflet with extern html content
Other adapted solution:
Add class hidden to sidebar ( Html element )

Create Legend on map

```
const legend = L.control({
  position: "topleft"
});
```

Get html content

```
const legend_html = $('#sidebar').html()
```

Add this to map

```
legend.onAdd = function() {
  let div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "leaflet-legend");
  L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", legend_html);
  return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);
```

[image: Fullscreen result]

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin is really confusing as there are several of them and the installation and usage instructions are confusing.
I'm using it with webpack and these are the fundamentals:

Add the following to package.json, using the latest stable version of the package:

```
"leaflet.fullscreen": "^2.4.0"
```

Run:

> npm install && make

Then in your js file (confirm the file paths below in your /node_modules dir:

```
import 'leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen';
import 'leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css';
```

And last of all you have a variety of ways to use the plugin:

```
map = L.map('map',
{
    fullscreenControl: true,
    // OR
    // fullscreenControl: {
    //     pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
    // }
}).setView([54.5, -2.3], 6);
```